# Align cart icon next to main logo - Shopify

Tags: css, css-float, shopify

I am trying to align the logo and cart icon in same line. Also there should be some space between the logo and the cart icon. Check the part `//...moved this code here - start`. That is the code I have added. It was earlier residing in a `ul` tag. Moved it here.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="logo" class="desktop-12 mobile-3">       
    {% if settings.use_logo_image %}
    <a href="/"><img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" style="border: 0;"/></a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a>
    {% endif %}

     //...moved this code here - start
     <ul id="cart" class="{% if settings.enable-hello %}desktop-3 {% else %}desktop-6{% endif %} tablet-6 mobile-3"> 
     <li class="cart-overview"><a href="/cart"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-2x"></i><span id="item_count">{{ cart.item_count }}</span></a>
        <div id="crt">
          {% include 'shopping-cart' %}
          {% if cart.item_count != 0 %}
          <a class="checkout-link" href="/cart">{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
     </li>
     </ul>
     //...moved this code here - end

  </div>
</div>
```

This is the output I am getting now.
[image]

And this is the output I am expecting.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes so under the div named logo; both logo image and then cart comes. So inorder to align in same line
for example below:

```
<div class="logo">
<div class="logoimg"></div>
<div class="cartimg"></div>
</div>
```

Style becomes like eg:

```
<style>
.logo{display:inline-block;width:900px}
.logoimg{float:left;width:400px;}
.cartimg{float:right;width:400px;}
</style>
```

Let me know for more details if needed.